# Get a list of all the files in a directory without using list.files in R?

Tags: r

I am having an issue where I am trying to get a list of all of the file names in a directory in R. Usually I would use `list.files()`. However, this particular folder has ~300,000 very small files in it. So when I call `list.files(pattern="*.csv", recursive = FALSE)`, my R Studio session just totally hangs. I waited a 24 hours last time & it never sorted itself out... Though oddly enough, my computer doesn't seem to be running out of memory at all.

My question is, is there a way to import a list of file names in a more efficient way? Or is there a way to import a smaller chunk of the file names at a time, eg Import the first thousand, then the second thousand, then the third thousand etc.

I wasn't sure what code samples to include--if there is something that'd be helpful, please let me know :)

Comment: There is no (easy) way around this. `list.files()`, also aliased to `dir()` calls the system level function.  You _could_ invoke `system()` or `pipe()` and rely on `ls` followed by `grep` _etc pp_ but that is both more and not as portable.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a way to use ```system('ls ', intern = T)``` on a windows machine? ```system("dir")``` doesn't seem to work, but I am less familiar with system commends. Alternatively, do you know if there is a way to do list.files(file 1 : file 5000) within a given folder?

Comment: On Windows, this (just like everything else) gets complicated quickly.  If you had Cygwin or MSys yes then you could do `ls`.  Likely you don't.  Seek help at your place of work.  Given your circumstances (30k files, Windows file system) this is a trivial task. (Yes, it likely would be on Linux but that is outside your control and not helping ...)

Comment: There is another way to use Linux on a windows machine, but it need to be windows10...Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I don't know if in this case `system()` could work if you launch R from this shell.

Comment: Hi All, I'll look into those! I do have Windows 10, so the WSL could be an option. Thank you!